# About Python Webcrawler

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am utilizing the code from "Introduction to computing using python" to make a web crawler. What I hope to do is avoid certain website such as google or yahoo because of its size and its potential to direct me to Andromeda.

Therefore, I created self.prohibited section for screening certain webpages.
However, it does not work. Do you have any suggestion to fix?
Many Thanks in advance.

```
def analyze(url):
    '''returns the list of http links
    in absolute format in the web page with URL url'''

    print('Visiting: ', url) # for testing

    # obtain links in the web page
    content=urlopen(url).read().decode()
    collector=Collector(url)
    collector.feed(content)
    urls = collector.getLink()

    # compute word frequencies
    content=collector.getData()
    freq=frequency(content)

    out=open('test.csv', 'a')
    print(out, 'URL', 'word', 'count')
    csv=writer(out)


    #print the frequency of every text data word in web page
    print('\n {:50}{:10}{:5}'.format('URL', 'word', 'count'))
    for word in freq:
        row1=(url, word, freq[word])
        print('\n {:50} {:10} {:5}'.format(url, word, freq[word]))
        csv.writerow(row1)

    print('\n {:50} {:10}'.format('URL', 'link'))
    for link in urls:
        print('\n {:50} {:10}'.format(url, link))
        row2=(url, link)
        csv.writerow(row2)

    return urls


class Crawler:
    'a web crawler'
    def __init__(self):
        self.visited = set()
        self.prohibited=['*google.com/*','*yahoo.com/*']

    def crawl(self, url):
        '''calls analyze() on web page url
        and calls itself on every link to an univisted webpage'''
        links=analyze(url)
        self.visited.add(url)

        for link in links:
            if link not in self.visited and self.prohibited:
                try:
                    self.crawl(link)
                except:
                    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

`link not in self.visited and self.prohibited` is mostly equivalent to `link not in self.visited`, as `self.prohibited` is always evaluated to `True` in this statement. (`self.prohibited` is a non-empty list)

I think you want to replace `self.prohibited` by this: `not any(re.match(x, link) for x in self.prohibited)`.
This code checks, for each prohibited regexp, if the link matches the regexp.

Comment: Oops. I think while I copy and paste it from my python and writing this article, that part was deleted or missed.

Comment: My answer still gave you the right piece of code ;)
I updated it to explain you better what it does.

Comment: @ArnoldChung can you update the question with corrected version, since now condition is definitely wrong as noticed by Valentin

Comment: @pmod Hello, I added another code which I fixed with Valentin's code. If you have any idea how I can fix this, please let me know. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @ArnoldChung First of all, you should update the question, not create new answer, since it's not an answer. So, I will have to flag it as not answer.

Comment: @ArnoldChung and the second, any() returns boolean, True if match found, so it should be "not any"